# how should i handle with error array to string conversion in yii2?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i keep getting error "Array to string conversion" when i try to make my checkbox list button.

this is my code for check box

```
$list = [0 => '8:00-9:00', 1 => '9:00-10:00', 2 => '10:00-11:00', 3 => '11:00-12:00', 4 => '12:00-13:00', 5 => '13:00-14:00', 6 => '14:00-15:00', 7 => '15:00-16:00', 8 => '16:00-17:00', 9 => '17:00-18:00'];
```

for this field

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'available')->checkboxlist($list);?>
```

i dont know where the error come from and what to do

this is my model code

```
<?php

 namespace frontend\models;

 use Yii;

 /**
 * This is the model class for table "timetable".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $day
 * @property string $available
 * @property string $notAvailable
 */
class Timetable extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'timetable';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username', 'day', 'available', 'notAvailable'], 'required'],
        [['available', 'notAvailable'], 'safe'],
        [['username', 'day'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'username' => 'Username',
        'day' => 'Day',
        'available' => 'Available',
        'notAvailable' => 'Not Available',
    ];
}
}
```

can someone tell me which part im doing wrong ?

[error trace 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lg6V.png)[error trace 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47ij4.png)[error trace 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTj83.png)[error trace 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCPru.png)[error trace 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMiAy.png)

Comment: show complete error trace till the bottom the `$list` is ok and should populate the checkboxes. also what version of Yii are you using

Comment: i already edit the question with the error trace in the picture. i'm using Yii Framework/2.0.15.1 (advanced). thank you in advanced

Comment: your error is while saving the mdel not populating the form you are assigning the array to the model field where as you should implode or use a separate table to add the available timing and you model rules are also messy, you are declaring the `available` and `notAvailable` as required ion the first line and then `safe` in the very next line

Comment: the errors only when i used the checkboxlist. if im using this code there no error and it insert in db just fine `<?= $form->field($model, 'available')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>` and also the model rules is auto generate using gii

Answer (score 0):

According to [yii2 guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#checkboxList()-detail), A checkbox list allows multiple selection, So the corresponding submitted value is an array.

Your code works with textInput because it's result is not an array.

you can use php array funtions like `implode()` to turn values to string.

Comment: hi, can you show me how to use implode in my code ?

Comment: please send me the part your sending data to db. this part needs fixing